# Wordpress tinyMCE additional button with popup window and "0" at the end

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce

Important parts of code:

javascript tinymceplugin:

```
init : function(ed, url) {

            ed.addCommand('addVocabularyLinkCallout', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    file : ajaxurl + '?action=addvocabularylinkbutton_function',
                    width : 350 + parseInt(ed.getLang('mytest.delta_width', 0)),
                    height : 250 + parseInt(ed.getLang('mytest.delta_height', 0)),
                    inline : 1
                }, {
                    plugin_url : url
                });
            });
            ed.addButton('addvocabularylink', {
                title : 'Dodaj link do słowniczka',
                cmd : 'addVocabularyLinkCallout',
                image : url+'/../img/tinymce/insertpopup.png'
            });

        },
```

wordpress ajax support, only for logged in users:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_addvocabularylinkbutton_function', 'addvocabularylinkbutton_function_callback');
function addvocabularylinkbutton_function_callback() {?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Single Link - Button</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
</html> 
<?php }; ?>
```

It is not important, that the window doesnt do anything itself, what bothers me is "0" at end of the code of the popup window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Single Link - Button</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
</html> 
0
```

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging here and there, I have found, that it is not a problem of TinyMCE, but wp_ajax callout. It needs:

```
die;
```

at the end.

So the correct code would be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_addvocabularylinkbutton_function', 'addvocabularylinkbutton_function_callback');
function addvocabularylinkbutton_function_callback() {?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Single Link - Button</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
</html> 
<?php 
    die;
}; 
?>
```